# Deploying a flask app with selenium on heroku

Tags: python-3.x, flask, heroku, selenium-chromedriver, flask-restful

I want to deploy my flask app which uses selenium to **scrape** a website and returns data in json. It's getting crashed due to chrome driver path which i've added in config vars, but still its not working. Is there any other way to make my web app run on heroku? I've added buildpacks too.

selenium settings:

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH"),options=options)
    options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
```

[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyDOf.png)

[heroku config vars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLTK.png)

[heroku buildpacks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lT4b6.png)

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: did u fix bro? i'm stuck here too

Answer (score 0):

I know I am answering late but may be this one be helpful...

Try by using these two buildpacks worked for me...

```
https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/google-chrome.tgz
https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/chromedriver.tgz
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).